# Prestashop 1.7.6.5 create custom hook

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to add new custom hook:
theme.yml

```
custom_hooks:
      - name: displayUnderTop
        title: displayUnderTop
        description: Add main menu in the header
```

and view:

```
{hook h='displayUnderTop'}
```

but in admin dashboard I don't see new hook. I tried to recompile template files but to no avail. How to make this hook appear on the "positions" list?

Answer (score -1):

Ok Solved:
i just unzip other theme, changed to new, and change back to classic theme. It work's :)